# Rails technique to execute javascript after redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Rails app (3.2.8) and turbolinks (*not sure if relevant*) enabled.

1. I have some information, a `link` on a users show page. (E.g. A notification that something has changed.)
2. When the user clicks on the link I want to direct him to the page **and**
3. Visually **highlight the elements that changed.**

Currently I'm planning to handle it like this:

Create the links so they are of the form:

`project2/comment.1453`

Create a `notifications controller,` which gets the `projects2` and the type of change `comment` and its id `1453`. So in theory I want to redirect to `projects2` and highlight the comment with id 1453 on that page. The problem is: After the redirect how do I highlight the comment?

notificationscontroller.rb (Pseudo code!)

```
def show
  project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  comment = Comment.find(params[:commment_id])
  redirect_to project AND highlight!
end
```

During my research I've come across Backbone, and it looks like Backbones router could solve this problem by responding to the url with a function (the highlighting of the comment). But I don't have any experience with Backbone.

I'm not sure what the general approach to this sort of functionality is. And would like to avoid going down the wrong path. Would be great if you could help me out.

Edit: Sort of a mini question: I'm not sure which character to use for `comment.1453` is `#`a better choice? (`comment#1453`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't run javascript after a redirect other than including javascript on the page you redirect to.

What you want is to carry information over from this request to the next (redirected) request.

The flash is a good way to do this. Normally you'ld use it for text messages:

```
redirect_to project, notice: "Project foo bar message"
```

or

```
flash[:notice] = "Project foo bar message"
redirect_to project
```

There is nothing that stops you from using other identifiers in the flash and storing JSON in their.

```
flash[:highlight_ids] = "[12, 43, 472, 482]"
redirect_to project
```

Then in your layout or somewhere extract this flash message to JavaScript:

```
var highlight_ids = <%= flash[:highlight_ids] %>;
```

Then do your javascript magic to highlight the actual elements.

Comment: I feel like this is a cleaner way than to store the info in a cookie, so I'm going to accept this answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One of possible ways:

Store the id (and possible object type if need to highlight not only comments) in the session or directly in the cookie (`show` action in your pseudo-code)

```
def show
  project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  comment = Comment.find(params[:commment_id])
  cookies[:highlight_id] = comment.id
  cookies[:highlight_type] = 'Comment' # optionally
  redirect_to project
end
```

In projects controller `show` action

```
def show
  ...
  if cookies[:highlight_id] and cookies[:highlight_type]
    @highlight_id = cookies[:highlight_id]
    @highlight_type = cookies[:highlight_type]
    cookies.delete[:highlight_id]
    cookies.delete[:highlight_type]
  end
```

And in the comments view

```
<div class="some_class <%= highlight(@comment, @highlight_id, @highlight_type %>" ...
```

Where `highlight` is a helper like

```
def highlight(object, object_id, object_type)
  if object_id and object_type and object.is_a?(object_type.classify.constantize)
    'highlighted'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled across this post and decided to add a solution that I'm using in Rails 4.1.

```
class CoolController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :js

  def controller_action
    # controller stuff

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {
        return redirect_to my_redirect_path, notice: "Successfully updated payment method!"
      }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

js file named `controller_action.js.erb` is executed and the page is successfully redirected to `my_redirect_path`.